# I am trying to transfer data to the server in the database from the front (react)

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm just learning react and I can't transfer some data to the server in any way, they come with a null value. Here's an example, I select a category from the list, but an empty value (null) comes, that's what json shows in the browser console. The same is true in the database in the column "case_category_id" the value is null
Example of output in the browser, after saving the card

```
{
    "original_name": "7",
    "author": null,
    "case_category": null,
    "article": 100,
    "pub_date": "2023-11-30T10:24:08.346215Z",
    "preliminary_hearing": "2023-01-01"
}
```

The code itself

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import MyInput from './UI/input/MyInput';
import MyButton from './UI/button/MyButton';

const AddBusinessCard = ({ create }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    original_name: '',
    author: '',
    case_category: '',
    article: '',
    pub_date: '',
    preliminary_hearing: '',
  });
  const [categoryList, setCategoryList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:8000/business_card/category/')
      .then(response => {
        setCategoryList(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching category list:', error);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setFormData(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!formData.case_category) {
      console.error('Please select a category.');
      return;
    }

    const formattedData = {
      ...formData,
      preliminary_hearing: new Date(formData.preliminary_hearing).toISOString().split('T')[0],
      case_category: parseInt(formData.case_category),
    };

    axios
      .post('http://localhost:8000/business_card/businesscard/', formattedData)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Business card added:', response.data);
        create(response.data);
        setFormData({
          original_name: '',
          author: '',
          case_category: '',
          article: '',
          pub_date: '',
          preliminary_hearing: '',
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error adding business card:', error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <div style={{ width: '400px' }}>
        <h2>Add Business Card</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <MyInput
            type="text"
            name="original_name"
            value={formData.original_name}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="Номер дела"
          />
          <MyInput
            type="text"
            name="author"
            value={formData.author}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="Автор"
          />
          <select
            name="case_category"
            value={formData.case_category || ''}
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            <option value="">Выберите категорию</option>
            {categoryList.map(category => (
              <option key={category.id} value={category.title}>
                {category.title}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          <MyInput
            type="text"
            name="article"
            value={formData.article}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="Статья"
          />
          <MyInput
            type="text"
            name="pub_date"
            value={formData.pub_date}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="Дата создания (не заполнять!!!!)"
          />
          <MyInput
            type="text"
            name="preliminary_hearing"
            value={formData.preliminary_hearing}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="Дата предварительного заседания"
          />
          <MyButton type="submit">Создать новую карточку!</MyButton>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddBusinessCard;
```

model in django

```
class Category(models.Model):
    '''6. Модель категорий дела'''
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        verbose_name='Название категории'
        )
    description = models.TextField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Описание'
        )
    slug = models.SlugField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
        )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)
        verbose_name = 'Категория дела'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категория дела'

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
```

Comment: Please share your views also

Comment: I haven't set up views yet, I'm just trying to connect the backend and the front end, then I'll configure everything
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The title is string in the Django Model.
`paresInt('text')` returns `NaN`.

## Solution

```
<select
  name="case_category"
  value={formData.case_category || ''}
  onChange={handleChange}
>
  <option value="">Выберите категорию</option>
  {categoryList.map(category => (
    <option key={category.id} value={category.id}>
      {category.title}
    </option>
  ))}
</select

const formattedData = {
  ...formData,
  preliminary_hearing: new Date(formData.preliminary_hearing).toISOString().split('T')[0],
  case_category: formData.case_category,
};
```

In Django, the id field is an auto-incrementing integer that is being used as the primary key for the model.
When a user selects an option, case_category property of formData will set to id and further it'll pass as payload to post request.